# Japanese for the tech industry

Tags: business-japanese

I've studied japanese for 6 years, equivalent of 3 years in college. I don't really have a formalized way to measure my Japanese level but I can read probably around 600-700 kanji and am more or less conversationally fluent.  I haven't taken a JLPT or anything like that but I want to get a job in the tech industry in Japan. Some of the globalized companies don't require your level of Japanese to be that high but some do require you to know "Business Level" or be able to take things like coding tests written entirely in Japanese.

I do want to expand the range of options for myself and I'm willing to dedicate a fair amount of time. Are there any good ways for someone at my level to learn business level or employment ready Japanese language? Does anyone who knows Japanese have experience in the tech industry and knows the kind of things I would need to know?

Comment: 600-700 kanji sounds (to me) like "tech industry" is unnecessary detail for now. Maybe focus on learning some more Japanese first (at least learn _reading_ the remaining jōyō kanji and the associated vocabulary). If you're conversationally fluent, that might go a lot faster than you might expect. Taking a JLPT test will also likely increase your chances. At your level, you can probably try for N3. Knowing more (general) Japanese isn't just good for _getting_ the job, but especially useful once you _have_ a job.

Comment: I forgot to mention, "Welcome to Japanese.SE!" but resource requests are off-topic for the main site. [We maintain a fairly comprehensive list of resources](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) on our "meta" page.

Comment: Here you go. Good luck! [日本語StackOverflow](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Learning most of the jōyō kanji is probably good, but there are some characters on the list learners don't really need to prioritize, like 虞 or 璽.  Sometimes I wonder if focusing on word frequency might not be a better approach, learning the characters as they learn the words.  But I dunno :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. **Are there any good ways for someone at my level for
>   learning business level or employment ready Japanese language?**

**A1.** First, let me suggest what is meant by measurable "business level" Japanese. When employers list or state that they are looking for someone in ◯◯ industry with measurable business level Japanese they are most likely referring to a higher level ([N2 or N1](http://www.jlpt.jp/e/about/levelsummary.html)) on the [Japanese Language Proficiency Test](http://www.jlpt.jp/e/index.html) (JLPT) or a score of [400 points or higher](http://www.kanken.or.jp/bjt/english/about/) on the [Business Japanese Proficiency Test](http://www.kanken.or.jp/bjt/) (BJT).

You can review the [JLPT "can do" statements](http://www.jlpt.jp/e/about/pdf/cdslist_e_all.pdf) to see what types of things you will need to be able to do to get a score at those levels. This list will also be helpful for you to evaluate yourself to see at about what level you are currently at.

Furthermore, when studying for these types of tests, purchasing a study guide online or at a bookstore (in Japan) and using that to study everyday has been most helpful for myself. You can find books to help you study such as the [日本語総まとめ series](http://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%B7%8F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81) or the JLPT [Official Book Trial Examination Questions](http://www.jlpt.jp/e/samples/sample12.html). The 日本語総まとめ series is especially helpful because it is set up into daily lessons making it easier to pace your study schedule. You may also consider the BJT Practice and Strategies Workbook Textbook ([ビジネス日本語能力テスト 模試と対策](http://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%E3%83%93%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B9%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%20%E6%A8%A1%E8%A9%A6%E3%81%A8%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96)).